# Need to fix if statement Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make sure that when user "likes" post it cannot be liked one more time by the same user. This is what I'm trying to do currently:

```
public function liked($id)
{
    $like = new Like();
    $post = Post::where('id', $id)->first();
    if($post->user_id != Auth::user()->id && $like->user_id != Auth::user()->id) {
        $like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $like->post_id = $post->id;
        $like->like = 1;
        $like->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

With this query I can like multiple times the same post. Can someone suggest some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take some time and read up on Laravel relations, they are really helpful in situations like this.

```
public function liked($id)
{
    $uid = Auth::user()->id;
    $likes = Like::where('post_id', $id)
                 ->where('user_id', $uid)->get();

    if ($likes->count() == 0)
    {
        $like = new Like;
        $like->user_id = $uid;
        $like->post_id = $id;
        $like->like = 1;
        $like->save();
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Note this code assumes the `$id` passed in is to a valid post.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function liked($id)
{
    // find the post
    $post = Post::find($id);

    // the logged in user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // user not allowed to like their own post
    if ($post->user_id == $user->id) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    // search each like for the post
    // if the user created the like, exit and redirect back
    // (relationship must be defined in the models)        
    foreach ($post->likes as $like) {
        if ($like->user_id == $user->id) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }

    // create and save the link
    $like = Like::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'post_id' => $post->id
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```